# Creating proportional symbology on layer in Notebook using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, arcgis-notebook

I am using an ArcGIS Notebook with ArcGIS Pro.

I am able to set graduate colors to my layers symbology. Although there is no renderer for proportional symbology.

Is there any way to do that?

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Data\project3.aprx")
mapx = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers("Places")[0]
sym = lyr.symbology`
 
sym.UpdateRenderer('Proportional Symbols')

lyr.symbology = sym
```

I am interested in this result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a workaround you can use for applying the layer a Propotional Symbols symbology.
Just put a layer in our project which exactly has the symbology you want and then use the funtion "ApplySymbologyFromLayer" to symbolize our new layer. So just leave your old layer with the right symbology there all the time, so you can use the symbology whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Symbology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/symbology-class.htm) help file, the supported renderers are discussed. As you will see Proportional Symbols is currently unsupported.

> The supported types are: GraduatedColorsRenderer,
> GraduatedSymbolsRenderer, SimpleRenderer, or UniqueValueRenderer.

Comment: Yes okay but maybe someone knows workaround